# R and Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, r, oracle, rodbc

Have anyone tried to use R and Oracle servers?

The credientials required for connection are:

```
HOST = somewhere.com
PORT = 1525
SERVICE_NAME = someservice
USERNAME = user
PASSWORD = pass
```

I've tried RODBC:

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("somewhere.com:1525/someservice", uid="user", pwd="pass")
```

But it only gives me these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("somewhere.com:1525/someservice", uid="user", pwd="pass") :
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM010, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long
2: In odbcDriverConnect("somewhere.com:1525/someservice", uid="user", pwd="pass") :
ODBC connection failed
```

Are there other ways to connect to Oracle?

Thanks all

Comment: I use RODBC to connect to an Oracle DB every day. Works fine. Have you set up your DSN?

Comment: Better to use [`Roracle` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html): better performance and DBI compliant.

Comment: I did not setup my DSN, but why does the oracle client doesn't need to have a DSN setup in the ODBC Data Source Administrator to connect? I could just type in the above fields and it just connects using a normal client.

Comment: Tried to use ROracle once, however it gives the error:
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0/library/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll': Even though I checked the dll and it exists
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’

Comment: That's not how ODBC works. You need a driver and then to set up a DSN. ROracle would work as well, but you'd need to compile it yourself, a process which I've found to be somewhat finicky. RODBC would be much simpler (with some performance loss, as noted).

Comment: If you choose to go the RODBC route, you should read its [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf) _very_ carefully (particularly the appendix on installation). It goes into extreme detail that will answer nearly every possible question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try RODBC first, however, it seems to be difficult to setup :S