# ODBC connection for 64 bit R and 64 bit MS access Database

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc

I am using 64 bit windows and 64 bit R, when I am trying to establish a **ODBC connection** it is throwing error:

**Warning messages:**

> 1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=C:/Users/anji/database.accdb") :
>     [RODBC] ERROR: state IM010, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long
>
> 2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=C:/Users/anji/database.accdb") :
>     ODBC connection failed

Please help me.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the problem if you don't provide us with your code.  Are you using `odbcConnect`, `odbcDriverConnect`, or `odbcConnectAccess`?  You have 64 bit R and 64 bit Windows, but is your version of Access 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274161/r-and-oracle-sql or this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/134723 helps. Found by internet search for error message  `odbc Data source name too long`.

Comment: Try using backslashes as used in Windows environments. For R you escape by doubling the slashes: `DSN=C:\\Users\\anji\\database.accdb`